# Create post link in telegram saved messages section

Tags: telegram

Every channel or group in one's telegram account has a 'copy post link' feature for every post made in that channel or group?
Following is an example of such a copied link from a post
https://t.me/c/1136558241/1504
Where the channel's unique id is 1136558241 and the post id is 1504
If this channel is accessible to someone then they can land to this post (with id 1504) using the above link without spending much efforts in searching the whole channel.

Actual Issue -
This 'copy post link' is not available in the Saved messages section. Hence it is not possible to reach to any post in a hassle free manner.
For not having the option of copy post link it is also not easy to get the unique id of once Saved messages section.
I could extract the unique id by using the 'Export chat history' option on the saved message chat window.
However once i create a similar link as above by replacing the unique id of the saved messages like - https://t.me/c//1504 and try to reach to the specific post using this link, it opens the saved message chat window, but goes at the end of the chat AND NOT landing in the desired post dynamically.

Any idea how to reach to saved messages post in telegram dynamically?
I wish to do this to create kind of an indexing in the saved messages & get my important documents easily when needed without wasting much time in searching.
Note - I can use/ create a different channel where this 'copy post link' works but I will like to get this done in saved messages since there is already a lot of important data

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you found an anser to this? I have the same problem, I need a link to the original message exporting the saved message chat.
It would be nice even an API method contacting the telegram server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunally that's not possible.

If we look at Telegrams [`exportMessageLink`](https://core.telegram.org/method/channels.exportMessageLink) documentation, we see:

> Get link and embed info of a message in a [channel/supergroup](https://core.telegram.org/api/channel)

Your 'saved messages' chat is not a channel nor a supergroup, therefore it's not possible to create links like that

Comment: Thanks @0stone0. Is there a way I can programmatically transfer all my saved messages data in existing order to a new channel or group? Like will use that as the saved messages zone going forward!